# Changing the colour of equations produce in LaTeXiT

Tags: math-mode, color, latexit

I am using LaTeXiT on my Mac to produce things like equations (both singular and as align-environments) and matrices as images which I can then copy and paste into a PowerPoint presentation. I want the colour of the produced math-text to be different from the default black colour - how do I change this on LaTeXiT?

There is an option for font-size and colour on the bottom left of my LaTeXiT screen, but changing the colour there doesn't do anything.

Comment: I haven't used this app for years, but did you load a color-related package? I don't think LaTeXit does it by default. The `xcolor` package should do what you want in math mode.

Comment: You can load `xcolor` by modifying LaTeXit's default preamble or by creating your own personal preamble.